# Google Analytic's and Universal PHP Footers

Tags: php, google-analytics

If I have a universal Footer, `include('footer.php');` on my page - will the google analytic's script I just put there be able to track my page views?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Analytics runs in the browser after the PHP has generated the page's HTML. So if you use a PHP include to include a common footer containing the Google Analytics code it will track the page view for all of those pages.

Comment: for all those (individual) pages right? That's pretty cool <3 google